# C : How to check end of input from keyboard or file while using scanf one char at a time

Tags: c, input, io, scanf

I have to write a program  in C for class that reads in one character at a time and we have to use scanf. I got it to work with input from only the keyboard however, my teacher will be testing the code with file redirection as well.

```
int end;                                    //return value of scanf
int length1;                                //length of string exp1
char temp,                                  //temp char for input
char exp1[81];                              //string

printf ("Please enter in a regular expression:\n");
end = scanf ("%c", &temp);

while (temp != '\n' || end == 1) {          //check if end of input
   length1 = check(temp, length1, exp1);    //returns length of exp1

   end = scanf ("%c", &temp);               //scan next char for loop
}
```

I've been at this one tiny problem for hours trying to figure it out so any pointers are helpful. Thanks!

EDIT: I've tried using the kbhit() function in an if statement to check if they typed in the input or if the input is from a file. However, I don't have conio.h, is there any alternative while still using scanf?

Answer (score 5):

Your narrower-scope question has already been answered, but let me give you a piece of good advice. If you are not forced to use `scanf()` in class (i. e. you are writing real, production code), then

**Just get rid of `scanf()`.** It's evil. It does not do what you think it does.

If you want to get one character at a time, then use the function that gets one character at a time. And that is `fgetc(stdin)`.

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    /* process `c' */
}
```

Comment: Yea I know, the only reason he's forcing us to use scanf is to show us how terrible it is. I never use scanf in any of my other programs. But my question still has not been solved, I need to figure out a way to get input from the keyboard and a file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare scanf output with `EOF`

```
while(scanf("%c", &temp) != EOF)
{
}
```

You could convert this to something like:

```
do{          

   length1 = check(temp, length1, exp1);    //returns length of exp1

   end = scanf ("%c", &temp);               //scan next char for loop

}while (temp != '\n' && end != EOF) ;
```

Comment: It becomes an infinite loop with keyboard input when I compare it to EOF in the while loop. And when used in the do while loop it still only takes in one line of the input file, it stops when it hits the new line. How can I do it without comparing temp to \n?

Comment: This is wrong, `scanf()` doesn't return `EOF` if a conversion failure occurs. It returns the number of arguments successfully converted. It only returns `EOF` if the input ended before the first conversion match or failure, which is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` returns `EOF` if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. So you may check on that. But you only read one character each time, that doesn't seem necessary since you already check if the return value if `1`.

I think the error is in the logic in your `while` condition, it should be:

```
 while (temp != '\n' && end == 1)
 //                  ^^
```

Comment: This only works for keyboard input, not file input since the file will have \n. I need a way that doesn't compare temp to \n so I can read the whole file.